# Checks whether log event should be logged or not NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, nlog

I'm using Nlog library for logging in my ASP.net website. I want to check whether log event should be logged or not in order to create a "StackFrame". according to Nlog documentation they have given "Check" method to do this. but it doesn't work for me. the Check method is not available. it would be really great if someone can help me on this.

http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/M_NLog_Filters_Filter_Check.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should use filters as described here, https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filters

Comment: thank you for your reply Xharze but i really want to use "Check" method given in the following link in my c# code rather than in Nlog.config file. The problem is that method is not visible even-though i add the required namespaces. its really great if you can help me with this a c# example.

Comment: The Check method is protected, and therefore only available when creating a custom filter